# How can I create a proxy in azure with specific redirection rules?

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

My goal is to access a 3rd party website "externalsite.com" via a proxy in Azure in order to keep my public IP address fixed regardless of whether the origin of my request is within an Azure App Service or from my dev environment.

So ideally I would send a request to "mynewproxy-externalsite.com" and it'll know to redirect to "externalsite.com".

Also it would be even better if this could handle websockets too, but that isn't essential.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged your post with azure-virtual-network I asume that your app is running on a azure app service running with vnet-integration.
If public static ip is your main goal I would consider Azure Nat gateway instead of of a proxy ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nat-gateway/nat-overview). This is a simple and relative low cost option for getting public outbound ip from your app service on the transport layer. Basicaly this works by routing traffic from your vnet through this service which has a public ip.   This will also handle web sockets.